# How to use generated HTML legends to enable or disable datasets in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

You can [generate HTML legend in Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) as below:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {...});
myChart.generateLegend();
```

However, you cannot click the legends to enable or disable datasets. See [this exmaple in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyougo/uv6s5mw9/).

Is there any good way to toggle (i.e., enable or disable) datasets by clicking the generated HTML legends?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use [the getDatasetMeta API](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html) to realise it, as demonstrated below:

```
$('#js-legend').click(function(e) {
  var targetLi = $(e.target).closest('li');
  targetLi.toggleClass('inactive');

  if (targetLi.hasClass('inactive')) {
      myChart.getDatasetMeta(targetLi.index()).hidden=true;
  } else {
    myChart.getDatasetMeta(targetLi.index()).hidden=false;
  }    
    myChart.update();
});
```

You can find [the example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jyougo/neb34wrq/2/).